# Errors in installing php composer on windows

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

While installing the composer to user the laravel framework, I got some errors :

```
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation failed
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation failed
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation failed
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

I'm sure that the `Openssl` in `php.ini` is enable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the OpenSSL extension enabled does not mean it is configured correctly.

It fails to validate the certificate for `getcomposer.org`. That means either some man-in-the-middle server messes with your request or you somehow did not configure the set of default CA Authorities. Your server operator can tell you more.

Comment: So what I have to do ?

Comment: Best thing would be to read to manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php It does have step by step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using wamp on windows 7, and I already enabled the openssl.dll in php.ini, still report the same error.
my problem is caused by the network provider,and I have no idea what's wrong with the them.
after I connect to a VPN network .it works like a charm.