# Composer "Download failed" Error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i use xampp in Windows and my PHP Version is 5.5.15 .
need to install composer for Start work with laravel framework. but my problem is here, when i want install composer, be faced with this error :

```
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation failed
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation failed
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation failed
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

What should I do?
and is there a way to install laravel without using composer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errors in installing php composer on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900656/errors-in-installing-php-composer-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have to set the environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE to the path of the PEM file of the ssl-certificate downloaded from the following link : http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.

It took me a lot of time to figure this out.

For a detailed answer, you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590842/cannot-install-composer-on-mac-os-x

Comment: as that question was removed can you provide a detailed answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kaspersky, try to **disable** the **Encrypted connection scanning** (or set the *Scan encrypted connections upon request from protection components* option) and try again.

[image]

[image]

If you have the *Always scan encrypted connections* you can get errors like these:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed



[RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/doctrine/inflector.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.
  - https://github.com/doctrine/inflector.git
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\User\my-project\vendor\doctrine\inflector'...
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/doctrine/inflector.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
  - git@github.com:doctrine/inflector.git
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\User\my-project\vendor\doctrine\inflector'...
    Host key verification failed.
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```