# Composer update fails while updating from packagist

Tags: php, openssl, xampp, composer-php, php-5.6

While executing composer install/update I have got the following error from openssl:

> The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>   Failed to enable crypto
>   failed to open stream: operation failed
>   https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

I am using:

1. PHP 5.6.3 (cli) (built: Nov 17 2014 15:16:53)
2. XAMPP stack 5.6.3-0
3. ubuntu 14.04

composer diag shows:

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json"  file  could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version:
```

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed

php -r 'var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());' shows:

```
array(8) {
["default_cert_file"]=>
string(33) "/opt/lampp/share/openssl/cert.pem"
["default_cert_file_env"]=>
string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE"
["default_cert_dir"]=>
string(30) "/opt/lampp/share/openssl/certs"
["default_cert_dir_env"]=>
string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR"
["default_private_dir"]=>
string(32) "/opt/lampp/share/openssl/private"
["default_default_cert_area"]=>
string(24) "/opt/lampp/share/openssl"
["ini_cafile"]=>
string(0) ""
["ini_capath"]=>
string(0) ""
}
```

For php 5.5.19 everything is Ok.

Comment: Please, explore this issue: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798

Comment: If you are using **Kaspersky**, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54791481/3549317

Answer (score 32):

I found a solution to this

I'm running:
FreeBSD 10.1
Apache2.4
PHP 5.6.3

To find the CA file I ran this command

`> locate cacert.pem`

Result was:
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem

Then open the php.ini file and
change this:

> ;openssl.cafile=

To this:

> openssl.cafile=/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem

Note: This directive is only available on php 5.6.x

Then restart Apache

Comment: if you are unable to locate your copy of cacert.pem file, its available for download at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.6.3 on MAC. But unable to find the openssl.cafile=

Comment: Works on ubuntu for `php composer.phar install` my zend framework 2 application.

Comment: I just did all this in php 7.0 but it's still not working (;_;) wtf man? I restarted apache as well

Comment: works for me on php 5.6.40 and ubuntu 18.04 in vagrant

Answer (score 12):

I solved the problem with the SSL error by adding the SSL certificate to the XAMPP certificates folder.

```
// navigate to a directory to save the certificate
cd /Downloads

// download a certificate
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

// rename and move the file to the Xampp certificates folder
mv cacert.pem /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cert.pem
```

Don't forget to restart your apache!

Comment: Thank you! For information, on Linux the path is: sudo mv cacert.pem /opt/lampp/share/openssl/cert.pem

Comment: To find the location the following can be used: `php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"` (look for the value of `default_cert_file`.).

Answer (score 12):

I am using Mac OS Sierra and when I was trying to update the composer using the command `/usr/local/bin/composer self-update` I kept getting the error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                          
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with co  
  de 1. OpenSSL Error messages:                                                                     
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed                 
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                           
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I fixed it following these steps:

1) Create the local database using the command:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
```

2) Locate the cert file:

```
locate cacert.pem
```

3) Check the location of the php.ini file:

```
php --ini
```

4) If the 'Loaded Configuration File' for `php.ini` file is showing as `(none)`, copy the file `/etc/php.ini.default` to `/etc/php.ini`:

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

5) Open the `php.ini` file and edit the  `;openssl.cafile=` line by uncommenting it and appending the link to the cert file location:

```
openssl.cafile=/Users/me/.composer/cacert.pem
```

Thats it. Now, when you run the composer update, it will work fine.

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same exact issue on Windows even after adding valid latest certificate downloaded. I'm running composer behind proxy, So i've to add environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy.

My environment:
PHP 5.6.33
Windows 7 64 bit
Composer version 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17

I downloaded latest certificates [CA Bundle](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt) and updated following paths in my php.ini still didn't work.

```
curl.cainfo = C:\Certificates\ca-bundle.crt
openssl.cafile= C:\Certificates\ca-bundle.crt
openssl.capath=C:\Certificates
```

Then did following steps

1) Open chrome browser and navigate https://packagist.org/

2) Click on the little Secure Lock icon

3) Click on Certificates Valid

[image]

4)Open Certificate Path tab and you will see the following path levels

[image]

5) Need to export the certificate for both 1&2 marked in the image

6) To export certificate, click on view Certificate, Got to Details Tab and click on Copy to file

[image]

7)choose BASE 64 encoding

[image]

8) click on Next and save that file to a location, Do this for No. (2) shown in setp 4

[image]

9) Open the .cer file and copy the content to the end of .crt file which you used to configure in php.ini

Then try running comport install - It's worked for me

Process should be same if you see composer throwing ssl error when accessing sites over proxy.

Answer (score 6):

Adding openssl.cafile to php.ini worked for me too. 
Instead of looking for the cert file, I downloaded it directly:

curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem > cacert.pem

and then just pointed openssl.cafile setting to it.

Comment: It is a security issue to download from an insecure source (http) to root certificates. Only amateurs do that and then they get hacked.

Comment: @Kwadz use the https link instead, put the file onto your server via SSH/SFTP/SCP.

Answer (score 5):

1.

```
php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"
```

```
array(8) {
  ["default_cert_file"]=>
  string(31) "/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem"
  ...
}
```

2.vim php.ini

```
[openssl]
openssl.cafile=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

```
composer clearcache
```

This worked for me when I get error :

> https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Comment: Now I get the following error: `curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`, how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

On the mac with XAMPP:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl

sudo curl -O -k http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

sudo mv cacert.pem cert.pem
```

Stop and Restart Apache

Answer (score 1):

**First**: Check certificate file location which will be in `default_cert_file` key, you will found it in `openssl_get_cert_locations()` its a php openssl function. You can run it as follows:

```
$ php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"
```

**Output in my system**

```
    Array
    (
        [default_cert_file] => /opt/lampp/share/openssl/cert.pem
        [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
        [default_cert_dir] => /opt/lampp/share/openssl/certs
        [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
        [default_private_dir] => /opt/lampp/share/openssl/private
        [default_default_cert_area] => /opt/lampp/share/openssl
        [ini_cafile] => 
        [ini_capath] => 
    )
```

**Second**: Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem:

```
$ wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

**Third**: Copy `certificate.pem` file into `default_cert_file` location:

```
$ sudo mv cacert.pem /opt/lampp/share/openssl/cert.pem
```

** FROM https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3346 **

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add a simple answer.

**Your problem**: The composer is unable to download dependency files due to an incorrect certificate, either it is corrupt, incorrect, or not in place at all.

**Your potential easiest solution**: Download a new certificate and tell Composer to use the new one.

Step 1: Get CA Certificate from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

Step 2: Use the following command to use new certificate
`composer config --global cafile "<file_path_including_cacert.pem"`

Answer (score 0):

For us, this issue only seemed to affect one of our private repositories.  It may have had something to do with certs or a corporate firewall, but it seemed intermittent so we weren't able to confirm before we found a different fix.

Inside composer.json, we changed the repository URL from the https to the ssh variant and added the `"no-api": true`option:

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:our-user/our-repo.git",
      "no-api": true
    }
]
```

With that edit, composer update/install operations were able to complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this configuration to your composer.json file.

```
"config": {
"secure-http": false
}
```

Here is an full example of a working composer.json file

````
  "repositories": [{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "http://packagist.org"
  }],
  "require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "secure-http": false
  }
}
```
````

Comment: you never want to go the insecure route.  You want to always fix the security errors, not brush them aside and ignore them.  There is a reason for the error!