# Installing laravel 5.1 via composer SSL3 certificate error

Tags: linux, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1, ubuntu-15.04

I'm using ubuntu 15.04 just installed, first I try to install composer, 
with "curl -sSk composer-link | php". I add -k because of getting ssl error.

Next: I try to install laravel with "composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist" command and s... happens.

composer get error -> SSL3 which is in below :

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "packagist/packages.json/link" file could not be downloaded: SSL
   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify
  failed
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed

---

Notes: I try to install cercitifate which is cacert.pem , change opensll location in php.ini but still not works. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Did you install mcrypt?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem caused in same the link below (possible duplicate post)
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206719/composer-update-fails-while-updating-from-packagist)

Go and check php.ini be sure ;openssl.cafile=... not comment line.

1-) locate cacert.pem
2-) change ;openssl.cafile= to openssl.cafile=/path/from/first/step/cacert.pem