# How to send emails with Symfony 4 Swiftmailer from a local machine running on Windows 10?

Tags: symfony, wampserver, swiftmailer, ovh

I'm trying to send emails with Symfony 4, Wamp and [fake sendmail](https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/) on Windows 10 but without success, I'm hosted on [OVH](https://www.ovh.com/). I want to specify that I have a site hosted on OVH with same parameters running on Symfony 2 and Swiftmailer works perfectly.

Here is my Symfony .env line for Swiftmailer:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.dnimz.com:465?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=simslay@dnimz.com&password=***
```

Here is part of my Symfony controller for Swiftmailer:

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
    ->setFrom(array($this->container->getParameter('mailer_user') => 'dnimz'))
    ->setTo($user->getEmail())
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'emails/email_registration.html.twig',
            array('username' => $user->getUsername())
        ),
        'text/html'
    );

try {
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);    
    $this->addFlash('notice', 'mail envoyé !');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->addFlash(
        'notice',
        '<strong>Le message n\'a pu être envoyé !</strong>'
    );
}
```

Here is my sendmail.ini from fake sendmail:

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.dnimz.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=simslay@dnimz.com
auth_password=***
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=
force_recipient=
hostname=
```

Here is my php.ini mail function part:

```
SMTP =smtp.dnimz.com
smtp_port =465
sendmail_from = "simslay@dnimz.com"
sendmail_path = "C:/wamp64/sendmail/sendmail.exe"
mail.add_x_header = On
```

When sending the email, I've got this warnings and error:

> [debug] Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
>
> 2017-12-29T18:44:09+00:00 [debug] Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
>
> 2017-12-29T18:44:09+00:00 [debug] Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.dnimz.com:465 (Unknown error)
>
> 2017-12-29T18:44:09+00:00 [error] Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.dnimz.com [ #0]

I don't know why these errors occur?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you either don't have OpenSSL installed or there is a certificate error. I remember a similar issue as the first warning  regularly occuring with composer on Windows. The solution was to install a missing certificate (just place it in your certs folder in your WAMP-installation).

For reference see:

- https://akrabat.com/ssl-certificate-verification-on-php-5-6/
- [Composer update fails while updating from packagist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206719/composer-update-fails-while-updating-from-packagist/27254240#27254240)
- https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798#issuecomment-59812991

Comment: Thank you dbrumann but it didn't solve the problem and Composer works fine, I'm still working on this...