# Symfony 4 SwiftMailer Gmail : Email not sent

Tags: php, gmail, swiftmailer, symfony4

I'm currently working on a Symfony 4 application and I need to send emails throught Swift Mailer.
When I send an email, I receive the email spooled but I don't get it in my Gmail Mailbox.
I allowed unsecure apps in my gmail configuration.

This is my mailer URL from .env file : MAILER_URL=gmail://ep****@gmail.com:PASSWORD@localhost

This is my swiftmailer.yaml:

```
    #config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml
    swiftmailer:
        url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
        spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

This is my controller function:

## src/Controller/AccountController.php

[image: After completing a form]

This is the documentation I've followed :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html

I've checked these questions but they don't give me the answer : [How to send emails with Symfony 4 Swiftmailer from a local machine running on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027178/how-to-send-emails-with-symfony-4-swiftmailer-from-a-local-machine-running-on-wi?rq=1) , [mailer symfony 4 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230130/mailer-symfony-4-not-working?rq=1)

Please, I need help. I've looked for the solution all day long. I get no errors but I don't receive the mail.
Thanks in advance. Any link can help me.

Comment: please refrain from posting a snapshot of the code instead of the code itself

Comment: Did you set up a CRON job to process the spool? Did you try omitting the spool config setting? Is spooling a requirement?

Comment: I didn't set it. I tried omitting the pool but there's no change.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it? @SalveSafari

Comment: Yes, I solved it :) Please, read below

Comment: This is my solution. It works perfect on symfony 4.x
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542824/2400373

Answer (score 14):

Problem solved!!
Put this configuration instead of using the URL env variable

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:        gmail
    username:         ****@gmail.com
    password:         *******
    host:             localhost
    port:             465
    encryption:       ssl
    auth-mode:        login
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
    stream_options:
        ssl:
            allow_self_signed: true
            verify_peer: false
            verify_peer_name: false
```

Comment: Merci! That made the trick. Any idea why the .env file not working ?

Comment: I noticed going from Symfony 3 to Symfony 4 local SMTP is not enabled anymore. To use local SMTP in your .env set MAILER_URL=smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode=

Comment: Sage answer. Saved hours of frustration. Thank you @Selve!

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but the URL format requires full settings. I don't think SwiftMailer parses the URL to detect a specific transport (like `gmail`) to configure the reset by itself.

The following format worked for me:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587?encryption=tls&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, you will need enable "[Allow unsafe logins](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879)" in a Google Suite or Gmail account since they prevent access via SMTP.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out the spooler line

```
swiftmailer:
url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
#spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

Comment: Thank you so much you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

MAILER_URL must be url encoded. Check out the documentation at:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html#configuration

If your password had some special characters in it, that needed to be url encoded, it won't work.

Hope it helps.