# How to send email by my application using outlook account?

Tags: symfony4, swiftmailer

I have a problem with my application. I try to send email using outlook `smtp`. But it doesn't work.

Before I used gmail in the configuration and it worked perfectly :). And for a customer I tried to make it work with outlook. So I try to change the parameter `Mailer_url` in the `.env` file. After I made the change I tried the command to test:

```
php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send
```

It worked fine because I received the email. But when I try via my application it doesn't work.

This is my configuration:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.office365.com:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=myaccount@outlook.fr&password=mypassword
```

Someone have an idea ? Because I don't know why I can send email by command but not by my application. Thank in advance for help :).

Comment: You might want to URL Encode your configuration URL. Some characters may corrupt it. In example if your password contains special characters, such as `#` (your email contains a `@`)

Comment: Thank for your answer :). How can I Encode my configuration ?

Comment: Could have been faster to type this in your favorite engine than asking there. You can write a script that does that for you, using [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) in example

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915515/symfony-4-swiftmailer-gmail-email-not-sent)

Comment: It's really strange because my URL is encoded in the swiftmailer.yml if I'm not wrong:
`swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }`

Comment: Sorry for the double post I try to put information in the swiftmailer.yml

`swiftmailer:
    transport:        smtp
    username:         myaccount@outlook.fr
    password:         mypassword
    host:             smtp.office365.com
    port:             587
    encryption:       tls
    auth-mode:        login
    spool: { type: 'memory' }`

And set `MAILER_URL=null://localhost` in the `.env` file but always the same problem

Comment: And I try to encode my Mailer_URL but it doesn't work too. Someone have already work with outlook and swiftmailer ?

Comment: What part of the url are you encoding ? The whole part or the values of `username` and `password` ?

Comment: I suggest you to use the configuration file, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49137663/8398549). On production, you don't want to use the `.env` file, for security reasons

Comment: I encode juste username because the password it's not necessary. But there is something I don't understand for gmail I didn't have to encode the url and it worked fine. I already try with the swiftmailer.yml file but the same result.

Comment: Did you clear the cache after doing changes ?

Comment: Yes everytime I change configuration in the `.env` file or swiftmailer.yml.