# I am trying to install drush using composer . But facing 'crypto failed to open stream' issue

Tags: composer-php, redhat, drupal-8, drush

My composer version is 1.9.0

I am trying to install drush . but got some error.

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

Output :

> Changed current directory to /root/.config/composer
>
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: Failed to enable crypto   failed to open stream: operation
>   failed
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress]
>   [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev]
>   [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies]
>   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest]
>   [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

[image]

When I run `composer diagnose`

Output :
[image]

Comment: With what version of Drupal are you working? Drupal 8, then Drush must be required as local dependency.

Comment: Yes Drupal 8 , trying to install drush at some server

Comment: See https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/: `Drush only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency.`

Comment: composer global require drush/drush also same error

Comment: `$ cd path/to/my/drupal-project && composer require drush/drush && vendor/drush/drush/drush status`

Comment: `[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packages.drupal.org/8/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed`
I am running after going my project directory.. It may be server proxy issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199830/discussion-between-arif-and-leymannx).

Comment: It seems an ssl issue, check your certificates `php -r 'var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());'` and tell composer where to find them `composer config --global cafile '/path/to/cert'`

Comment: same issue after set cafile path of composer

Comment: check 2nd screen sort .. here some proxy issue come. it may server proxy issue

Comment: Some antivirus can intercept traffic and falsely report problems with package downloads. Did you try to disable it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer update fails while updating from packagist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206719/composer-update-fails-while-updating-from-packagist)