# Laravel 5.7 Installation Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to install laravel 5.7 by using this command

```
> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel new_project dev-develop
```

But it's reflecting following error, also i disabled antivirus and firewall.

> Installing laravel/laravel (dev-develop
>   b0651d2467f1428eadc505e1b3b4f5678611927c)
>     - Installing laravel/laravel (dev-develop develop): Loading from cache Created project in new_project
>
> > @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
> >     dependencies (including require-dev) Package operations: 71 installs,
> >     0 updates, 0 removals
> >       - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.5.1): Downloading (failed) Downloading (failed) Downloading (failed)    Failed to download
> >     vlucas/phpdotenv from dist: The
> >     "https://api.github.com/repos/vlucas/phpdotenv/zipball/8abb4f9aa89ddea9d52112c65bbe8d0125e2fa8e"
> >     file could not be downloaded : SSL operation failed with code 1.
> >     OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL
> >     routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
> >     Failed to enable crypto failed to open stream: operation failed
> >         Now trying to download from source
> >       - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.5.1): Cloning 8abb4f9aa8
>
> [RuntimeException]   Failed to clone
>   https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv.git via https,ssh protocols,
>   aborting.
>     - https,ssh://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv.git
>       Cloning into 'D:\xamppro\htdocs\neologicx.com\new_project\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv'...
>       fatal: I don't handle protocol 'https,ssh'
>
> create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source]
>   [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url
>   REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers]
>   [--no-scripts] [--no
>   -progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [] [] []

OpenSSL Installed

[image]

and enabled

[image]

Comment: is openssl installed ?

Comment: Yes it's installed i updated my question

Comment: Also check `phpinfo()` to make sure that PHP is actually "reading" openSSL correctly

Comment: openssl is enabled i checked,also updated my question

Comment: EVERYTHING was working fine till laravel 5.6, i've made like 20+ projects on it in 3 months but recent updates slowed me down :(

Comment: If you are using **Kaspersky**, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54791481/3549317

Comment: I don't use antivirus but thx for the reference very link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, my problem resolved by removing '%temp%' files from windows.
After that i got content-length mismatch problem resolved from this [Composer Content-Length Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch)

And then again i tried this "composer create-project laravel/laravel laravelproject1"  it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

--

```
laravel new myProject
```

Run these commands in order and you should be fine.

If you prefer to use the composer create project command, then run this:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Comment: OP stated he used your last command to perform the installation which still resulted in said answer, I therefor think your answer has little added value and does not answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, i tried but this doesn't work, it always keeps on failed at this => Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.1): Downloading (failed)

Comment: @ViperTecPro Have you tried following these directions from the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet#installation

Comment: i saw this at first "Valet requires macOS and Homebrew.", i don't have mac

Comment: @ViperTecPro Oh I'm sorry, I put the wrong info in the wrong thread. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

try `composer clear-cache` then `composer self-update`

Comment: when i run this composer self-update...it says this => The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed Failed to enable crypto failed to open stream: operation failed

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
install laravel 5.7:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravelproject1
```

Comment: Sorry Same ERROR :( , i think maybe something wrong with my windows.I Don't know what to do.