# How to solve Error while trying to install guzzle with composer?

Tags: php, iis, composer-php, guzzle

I'm getting the following error message when i try to install guzzle with `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`:

> You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
>   The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: 
>   https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
>   The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: 
>   https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  The "https://passthrough.fw-notify.net/static/auth_transparent.html?return=http://repo.packagist.org/p/guzzlehttp/guzzle%24b1cfe2f977a75ca671f5b311f8d4163989b8b742599dcfee07d767f01c8cd0e5.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. Op  
  enSSL Error messages:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed                                                                                                                                                                                  
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I tried to remove the semicolon before `extension=openssl` in my `php.ini` file. When its removed it throws:

> PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Which OS are you using

Comment: Im using windows 10

Comment: Did you install your WAMP stack manually, or are you using WAMPServer or XAMPP or something like that

Comment: Im using the IIS-Manager if you mean that

Comment: It looks like the extension is installed, but not configured properly. Please check this answer (and the link in the comment): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900656/errors-in-installing-php-composer-on-windows#comment36828799_23900883

Comment: Also, see this: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3833#issuecomment-82998728

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors in installing php composer on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900656/errors-in-installing-php-composer-on-windows)